# How to convert key format from camelCase to kebab-case using @SpringQueryMap on Feign?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I'm using the `@SpringQueryMap` annotation on my `Feign` client and I need to convert the format of the key that will be used as query params

```
data class MyQuery(
    val userId: String,
    val validAt: LocalDate
)


interface Client {

    @GetMapping("/v1/my-endpoint/")
    fun find(@SpringQueryMap queryMap: MyQuery): String
}
```

Using the example above the URL would be:

```bash
/v1/my-endpoint/userId=X&validAt=Y
```

How can I convert the key format from camel case to kebab case?

The final result should be:

```bash
/v1/my-endpoint/user-id=X&valid-at=Y
```

Comment: Try adding `@Param` annotation to both of those fields and add desired name as annotation value

Comment: @madteapot can you post an answer with examples?

Comment: @RafaAcioly you got working solution for this?

Comment: @akreddy.21 unfortunately no.

Comment: One way I explored is to have a custom encoder and decoder for feign client with a custom object mapper having set this property as objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);